# Using ID on HTML or BODY to set page-specific background image in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On a small currently unfinished bootstrap site (www.ehrenamt-ladenburg.de) I am trying to style the background image differently for each actual html file involved.

In my stylesheet for additional styling beyond bootstrap_3_3_1.css I am setting up the background image as a background url as in:

```
html {
    background: url(../images/tb20150807_210648_0216_8_0217_8_0218_8_0219_9_0220hdr-pm_1200.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This works for HTML as well as BODY elements - but not for DIVs or lower level elements (to cover the full background for a responsive page).

Initially I had thought of referencing an additional page-specific CSS file in each html file involved just to style the html background for each of the few pages of the site (which seem a reasonable way of getting things done).

A google search brought me to Stackoverflow and the "Page-specific css rules - where to put them?" thread (and caused me to sign up immediately because of the quality of the question and answer exchange I found).

Now the question for the experienced folks (I am still fairly new to serious bootstrap and css programming):

Couldn't I find a way to reference some sort of page ID in my css selectors to restrict a certain background image to a certain page?

So my question, I guess, is: how can I style BODY element (or HTML element for that matter) with an ID and reference it in a page-specific way? What is the syntax? Or what am I doing wrong?

With:

```
<body id="03_eal">
```

in the html file neither:

```
body#03_eal {
  background: url(../images/tb20150614_081922_231.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

nor:

```
#03_eal body {
  background: url(../images/tb20150614_081922_231.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

in the css file work for me.

Leaving out the ID portion in the css, it works fine using either BODY or HTML elements.

What would be the syntax? Or what am I doing wrong in trying to select HTML or BODY using an ID?

Answer (score 1):

Since the body has an id already. There is no real reason to include the tag selector in your css. ID's should be unique and using that specific id can be called just like this

```
#some-id {
    someKey: someValue
}
```

And no need for doubt. If you have access to your pages, you are more than allowed to add a class or id to that page to make it standout visually different than other pages.

You can also wrap your content in every page with a  tag and pass your class or id that way as well.

Ok so the reason it does not work for you is that you are starting your css id with 0 which converts to a number. Try removing the 0. Never start any css selector with a number. Try adding the number as a suffix and your issue will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Include your image in body and that will work fine. No need of including id or class in body just add below code. But keep in mind that you are using background image for your website, so compress its size. It shouldn't be much heavy in size.

```
body{
margin : 0; //optional
padding : 0; //optional
background: url(../images/tb20150807_210648_0216_8_0217_8_0218_8_0219_9_0220hdr-pm_1200.jpg);
background-position:fixed;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
```